# Can not connect mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database installed on Centos. I want to connect it from my local windows machine with Oracle SQL developer.
What I have tried:

1. bind address, change it to 0.0.0.0
2. skip-networking, change it to off.
3. disable centos firewall.

are there any further options that I can try?

Comment: Sounds like you have all the bases covered (I think). But why not use Oracle SQL Developers built in SSH tunneling to establish the connection?

Comment: 1. can you connect via the mysql client on centos? 2. have you opened the windows defender firewall?

Comment: I can connect with Oracle SQL Developers built in SSH to establish the conn

Comment: I can also connect on centos; and I have off the windows defender firewall

Comment: from my local machine, I can "telnet remoteIP 22" but failed with "telnet remoteIP 3306"

Comment: I found out the issue for my question, my ali cloud has security rule defined that block me with 3306, after set it to allow all, then all is well.